# Why is threading works on a single core CPU?

Tags: java, multithreading, multiplexing

To better understand Threading in Java, I wrote the following code

```
public class SimpleRunnableTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

       Thread t1 = new Thread(new TT1());
       t1.start();
       Thread t2 = new Thread(new TT2());
       t2.start();

       t2.join();
       t1.join();

       long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
       System.out.println("end-start="+(end-start));
       }
}
class TT1 implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class TT2 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is if I run `Thread.sleep(5000)` and `Thread.sleep(1000)` sequentially in `main` Thread, the time consumed would be `6 sec`, but since I am using Threading, it would only cost `5 sec` on a multicore CPU machine, and it did. But my question is:

Why is the result still `5 sec` on a single core CPU machine? Of course Threading is used, but isn't it just simulated threading by *time division multiplexing*?

My understanding of time division multiplexing is: assume `Thread.sleep(5000)` is task A, and `Thread.sleep(1000)` is task B, and we could break it apart to be : A1, A2, A3 ; B1, B2

Sequential is just :  A1, A2, A3, B1, B2

Time division Multiplexing Threading is just: A1, B1, A2, B2, A3

If it is, how come the first costs 6 seconds, and the 2nd only 5?

Am I way of base here?

Comment: One goes to sleep, thread context switch occurs, then the other executes (also going to sleep).

Comment: Threads implementation depends on system builder, at one sys it green, at other purple. Which you prefer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The result is 5, not 6, because the two threads can sleep simultaneously. Going to sleep by calling `Thread.sleep()` lets the other thread run, but the remaining sleep interval timer continues ticking for both threads.

Note that this applies only to sleeping (which uses nearly zero CPU), but not to doing useful work: in this case the timing on a single-core non-hyperthreaded CPU would indeed be additive. For example, if one thread needed to do five seconds worth of number crunching, and the other needed to do a second worth of number crunching, the total time for both threads would be six seconds.

Comment: Just tested, you are right. If the tasks is actual task instead of sleeping, Threading wouldn't effect the total time consumed on a `single-core non-hyperthreaded CPU`, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

By calling Thread.sleep(sleeptime), the Thread signals that it doesn't need the CPU for at least 'sleeptime' millis.

In the meantime the other thread can be executed.

Comment: But they can't really sleep `at the same time`, right? On a CPU level, the `same time` is achieved by `time division multiplexing`, which means what really happens is A sleep for a while, and then B, and then A, and then B... because the time interval is so small for each thread it creates the illusion of `sleeping at the same time`, isn't this how multi-threading achieved in the first place on a single core CPU? since at any rate, one CPU can't execute multiple commands at a single time, right?

Comment: "sleep" here is a synonym for "do nothing" - what should two threads prevent from doing nothing in parallel? Also, current CPU designs with pipelines and predictions do a lot in parallel, even on a single core